ClickHouse on MacOS Using ODBC bridge to Microsoft SQL Server
I am on MacOS, testing out ClickHouse suitability for our needs. I need to import data from big table on MS SQL  server in Azure, and trying to use ODBC connection. I’ve already defined the DSN using:
[ProdDWH]
Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Description=Connection to SQL Server
Server=tcp:someServer.database.windows.net,1433
Database=databaseName
UID=username
PWD=password
Encrypt=yes
TrustServerCertificate=no
Connection Timeout=30

when testing:
 isql -v ProdDWH
[28000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
However when testing with hardcoded user/pass like:
❯ isql -v ProdDWH username password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |

So, I am assuming the problem is with isql not reading user/pass correctly from config file. I am trying to continue in my local clickhouse, which I am running locally using the quick setup guide.
When I try in the ClickHouse cmd client:
SELECT *
FROM
   odbc(
    'DSN=ProdDWH',
    'databaseName',
    'SmallTableToTest'
  );

SELECT *
FROM odbc('DSN=ProdDWH', 'databaseNaame', 'SmallTableToTEst')

Query id: 403b9ac1-2b17-410c-844c-ed544d549fc0

Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 24.4.1.




Elapsed: 115.483 sec.

Received exception from server (version 24.4.1):
Code: 410. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: BridgeHelper: clickhouse-odbc-bridge is not responding. (EXTERNAL_SERVER_IS_NOT_RESPONDING)

I was trying to run the clickhouse-odbc-bridge manually in another terminal, but it seems its not available, and I googled for it as well..
On the locally running server, the trace error looks like:
2024.04.15 23:53:57.125914 [ 73088586 ] {403b9ac1-2b17-410c-844c-ed544d549fc0} <Error> TCPHandler: Code: 410. DB::Exception: BridgeHelper: clickhouse-odbc-bridge is not responding. (EXTERNAL_SERVER_IS_NOT_RESPONDING), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. Poco::Exception::Exception(String const&, int) @ 0x000000010dda729d
1. DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0x00000001072e96fd
2. DB::Exception::Exception<String>(int, FormatStringHelperImpl<std::type_identity<String>::type>, String&&) @ 0x000000010295a427
3. DB::IBridgeHelper::startBridgeSync() @ 0x000000010c6ad646
4. DB::(anonymous namespace)::ITableFunctionXDBC::startBridgeIfNot(std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>) const @ 0x0000000109dfa40a
5. DB::(anonymous namespace)::ITableFunctionXDBC::executeImpl(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, String const&, DB::ColumnsDescription, bool) const @ 0x0000000109df9e4e
6. DB::ITableFunction::execute(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, String const&, DB::ColumnsDescription, bool, bool) const @ 0x000000010a2224d5
7. DB::Context::executeTableFunction(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ITableFunction> const&) @ 0x000000010b145d80
8. DB::(anonymous namespace)::QueryAnalyzer::resolveTableFunction(std::shared_ptr<DB::IQueryTreeNode>&, DB::(anonymous namespace)::IdentifierResolveScope&, DB::(anonymous namespace)::QueryExpressionsAliasVisitor&, bool) @ 0x000000010acd316e
9. DB::(anonymous namespace)::QueryAnalyzer::resolveQueryJoinTreeNode(std::shared_ptr<DB::IQueryTreeNode>&, DB::(anonymous namespace)::IdentifierResolveScope&, DB::(anonymous namespace)::QueryExpressionsAliasVisitor&) @ 0x000000010acd501c
10. DB::(anonymous namespace)::QueryAnalyzer::resolveQuery(std::shared_ptr<DB::IQueryTreeNode> const&, DB::(anonymous namespace)::IdentifierResolveScope&) @ 0x000000010acc66e6
11. DB::QueryAnalysisPass::run(std::shared_ptr<DB::IQueryTreeNode>&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>) @ 0x000000010acc41ad
12. DB::QueryTreePassManager::run(std::shared_ptr<DB::IQueryTreeNode>) @ 0x000000010ac5f3c2
13. DB::(anonymous namespace)::buildQueryTreeAndRunPasses(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&) @ 0x000000010b538218
14. DB::InterpreterSelectQueryAnalyzer::InterpreterSelectQueryAnalyzer(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const> const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&) @ 0x000000010b536bf4
15. std::unique_ptr<DB::IInterpreter, std::default_delete<DB::IInterpreter>> std::__function::__policy_invoker<std::unique_ptr<DB::IInterpreter, std::default_delete<DB::IInterpreter>> (DB::InterpreterFactory::Arguments const&)>::__call_impl<std::__function::__default_alloc_func<DB::registerInterpreterSelectQueryAnalyzer(DB::InterpreterFactory&)::$_0, std::unique_ptr<DB::IInterpreter, std::default_delete<DB::IInterpreter>> (DB::InterpreterFactory::Arguments const&)>>(std::__function::__policy_storage const*, DB::InterpreterFactory::Arguments const&) @ 0x000000010b539911
16. DB::InterpreterFactory::get(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST>&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&) @ 0x000000010b4d5ae3
17. DB::executeQueryImpl(char const*, char const*, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, DB::QueryFlags, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, DB::ReadBuffer*) @ 0x000000010b8978a9
18. DB::executeQuery(String const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, DB::QueryFlags, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum) @ 0x000000010b894913
19. DB::TCPHandler::runImpl() @ 0x000000010c72330a
20. DB::TCPHandler::run() @ 0x000000010c739d1c
21. Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x000000010dc7390c
22. Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x000000010dc73e7e
23. Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x000000010de00d27
24. Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) @ 0x000000010ddfe541
25. _pthread_start @ 0x00007ff807c7b1d3
26. thread_start @ 0x00007ff807c76bd3

What am I doing wrong? is the bridge not supported on Mac? I am on M2 architecture
I also tried https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/install#macos-only-install-with-homebrew, but running into another issue:
The default config file doesnt exist, cask says the package is already installed:
❯ sudo clickhouse start
Will run /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config-file /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file /var/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid --daemon
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/clickhouse-server: No such file or directory
Code: 302. DB::Exception: Child process was exited with return code 127. (CHILD_WAS_NOT_EXITED_NORMALLY) (version 23.8.2.7 (official build))

I am not thrilled to spend a few hours trying to figure out a Docker container configuration with ODBC drivers, ODBC bridge as well as exposing ports, volumes for data persistance just for quick evaluation..

Did you get clickhouse-odbc-bridge to run? See https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/utilities/odbc-bridge#example
If you have done it correctly, you should see it with ps aux | grep 'clickhouse-odbc-bridge'
